# A very simple function take a very long time to execute

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

I created a new function in an Apps Script file, this function is very simple since it does nothing.

When I run it, it sometimes takes up to 60 to 70 seconds to execute.

What could slow down execution so much? My document has no other functions and no other code, no external libraries, is not shared, I have no trigger, I deleted all the contents of my file there is only one sheet totally blank ...

And when I copy-paste my file and open it, the execution time becomes fast again ... Except that I absolutely need the base file ...

Thanks for your help

```py
function test(){

}
```

**Edit :**

[see stackdriver here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/i1aO8.png)

```py
function test(){
  console.time("label");
  console.timeEnd("label");
}
```

Console.time said 1ms and function takes more than 50 seconds...

**Edit 2 :**

[Look at yesterday's execution](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MWZBL.png) (at the moment when everything has planted) that indicates more than 52000 seconds how is this possible?

Comment: Show execution transcript.

Comment: Explain how you time your function. Generally one uses `console.time("some label"); .... console.timeEnd("some label");` and views the result on Stackdriver...

Comment: How can you verify the execution time of your function?

Comment: Into stackdrive it shows "Duration 53s"... but I use console.time to log time and it shows 1ms... It looks like it finishes the function properly but the processing continues after ... While there is nothing else ... Can an element outside the code affect the processing time?

Comment: And the more time passes, the longer the function is to load, so that at some point the file starts to crash completely and I have to copy and paste the file (without changing anything) to start working again. ..

Comment: It's possible that the dashboard is  measuring time inaccurately. Can you refresh the dashboard  after a hour and see if the same function that ran at the same time shows the same duration.

Comment: The problem has been happening for about a week every day ... I have to copy and paste the file every time to allow my colleagues to work on it. And each time the dashboard always displays these huge computation times until it is so long that I have to copy and paste the entire file ... In the end I even get up to 50000seconds of computation time and the file crashes, look at yesterday's execution (image in edit of the post at the moment when everything has planted) that indicates more than 52000 seconds how is this possible? ...

Comment: @Jeck Forget the dashboard. It displays incorrectly. That's not the actual time the script runs.

Comment: After much research, it seems that the large number of protected cells in my document was the source of the problem. Not sure yet but I really think that was the problem.